# Oracle ORA-01830 with "WITH CLAUSE" - not with "HAVING CLAUSE"

Tags: oracle, date, string-formatting

we have a column in a table that looks as following:

FORECAST | TIME_BASIS

01.12.2014 | daily

01.12.2014 14:14 |  intraday

201435 | weekly

Please be aware, that we use European Date format (DD.MM.YYYY).

Now when I want to convert the daily string into a date, I see some strange behavior:

```
select day_id from 
(
  select to_date(forecast_time, 'DD.MM.YYYY') day_id
  from wfm_forecasts_new 
  where time_basis = 'daily' 
)
where day_id = '07.07.2014'
```

Results in:  *ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
*Cause:

*Action:*

When on the other hand I execute the query following way:

```
select day_id from 
(
  select to_date(forecast_time, 'DD.MM.YYYY') day_id 
  from wfm_forecasts_new a1 
  where a1.time_basis = 'daily'
) 
group by day_id
having day_id = '07.07.2014'
```

It returns me the expected result: 

*DAY_ID

07.07.2014*

Does anybody has a reasonable explanation for this behavior? We would need to have the possibility to use the where clause.

Your help is highly appreciated
Best regards,
Chris

Comment: There is no CTE ("WITH clause") in any of your examples. Not sure what your title refers to.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the order in which Oracle chooses to evaluate the predicates. It can choose to internally rewrite the query to make it more efficient.

From your point of view it seems obvious that in both queries the inner select will only look at and try to convert `daily` records; but it may in fact choose to apply the `to_date` function to every record and only then apply the `daily` filter.

That would mean that it tries to to `to_date('01.12.2014 14:14', 'DD.MM.YYYY')` for example, which is what generates the ORA-01830 error. You can look at the execution plan for both queries to see the difference, particularly in the 'access' and 'filter' information.

And it's behaving differently in the two queries, which isn't unusual as you've changed how the parser might choose to handle the sets of data. It will depend on your data and statistics though; when I run your original queries with a few records they both get the error.

You could add a hint to stop the predicate-pushing, or you could add a format check to the inner query, something like:

```
select day_id from 
(
  select to_date(forecast_time, 'DD.MM.YYYY') day_id
  from wfm_forecasts_new 
  where time_basis = 'daily' 
  and regexp_like(forecast_time, '^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}$')
)
where day_id = '07.07.2014';
```

You should really be doing one of these though as you currently have an implicit conversion in the outer `where` clause:

```
where day_id = to_date('07.07.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY');
where day_id = date '2014-07-07';
```

As the second query can also error in the same way you'd need something like for for either approach.

This may be a greatly simplified example, but if this is really what you're doing, I'm not sure why you aren't just filtering the string value:

```
select to_date(forecast_time, 'DD.MM.YYYY') day_id
from wfm_forecasts_new 
where time_basis = 'daily' 
and forecast_time = '07.07.2014';
```

... unless you want to allow for optional leading zeros in the day and month number, which the regular expression approach handles.